# Reset automatic code number every year on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

guys! i have automatic code number for invoice. the automatic code number is "xx/month/year". i want "xx" in my automatic code number reset to 1 when the year change or every 1 january. this is my code

```
function noinvoice()
```

{

```
$latest = Pengiriman::latest()->first();
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');

if (!$latest) {
    return '1/' . $month . '/' . $year;
}

$string = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", '', $latest->noinvoice);


return sprintf($string + 1) . '/' . $month . '/' . $year;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inspect your `$latest` object. If `$latest` doesn't exist OR its year doesn't match this year, then the invoice number is `1`. Otherwise, it's `$latest->noinvoice + 1`.

You never mentioned where you store your invoice creation date, so I'll assume you use the default `created_at` Laravel approach. For this task you should add one more condition to your `if` statement:

```
if (!$latest or date('Y', strtotime($latest->created_at)) != $year) {
```

Comment: thank you for your respond but my problem has been solved. so this is case closed. again, thank you for your time to answer my question :D